# Check whether custom EllipsizingTextView is ellipsized from ListView getView

Tags: java, android, android-listview, textview, ellipsis

I would like to create an expandable TextView which is shown in a `ListView`. In my `ListView` `Adapter`'s `getView` method I need to check whether a TextView is ellipsized to display an "expand" button.

I am using [EllipsizingTextView](https://github.com/triposo/barone/blob/master/src/com/triposo/barone/EllipsizingTextView.java) due to a [bug](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2254) in older Android versions.

EllipsizingTextView provides a method called `isEllipsized`. When I call this method in my `getView` method for the EllipsizingTextView I always get `false` as result. As I found out, the  `isEllipsized` method only works for views that have already been drawn.

As a result I tried to invoke `isEllipsized` from a separate `Runnable` using `TextView.post(Runnable runnable)`. This works for the first items displayed in the EllipsizingTextView after first load of list items.

However, when I scroll down `isEllipsized` always returns false. When I then scroll up again `isEllipsized` returns the correct boolean value for each list item.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Thanks for any hints.

Here is my getView method which I have in a separate Class:

```
private EllipsizingTextView textView;
private int position;

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null, false); 
        holder.text = (EllipsizingTextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.label);       
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    } 

    holder.text.setText(position + " " + this.text);

    this.textView = holder.text;
    this.position = position;

    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d("tag", TestObject.this.position +
                    " isEllipsized " + TestObject.this.textView.isEllipsized());
        }
    };
    holder.text.post(r);

    return convertView;
}
```

and my XML:

```
<com.example.listviewtest.EllipsizingTextView
  android:id="@+id/label"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:ellipsize="end"
  android:maxLines="5"
</com.example.listviewtest.EllipsizingTextView>
```

Comment: Related/dupe: [Detect whether TextView in ListView is ellipsized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855505/detect-whether-textview-in-listview-is-ellipsized)